# Stop anchor from making font awesome icon blue?

Tags: css

For some reason whenever I make a font awesome icon have it inside an anchor, it turns blue, and I cannot disable it the normal way, via css:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is a link to the codepen, as you can see at the footer the github icon is blue:

http://codepen.io/EuanR/pen/XbOdgR

Answer (score 7):

You can add the following CSS to make the link inherit the color of the text around it:

```
a {
  color:inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is that `text-decoration:none;` does not prevent a link from changing color; it just prevents the underline.

To prevent the color change, you have to override the color:

```
a {
   text-decoration:none;
   color: inherit;
}
```

And this is not related or caused by font awesome

Comment: No idea why this has *any* downvotes as it is the proper answer.

Comment: I don't get it either.

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome's Icons are inputed in `<i>` tags, you can just call the `<i>` tag.

```
i{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the color attribute:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}
```

or if you want the rest of the link blue, but the icon in other color:

```
a i {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set a color on the link:

```
.modal-footer a {
  color:red;
}
```

**[codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNMmoj)**